# Is a relative pronoun commonly used as a third person pronoun? (Metamorphoses I.583-587)

Tags: classical-latin, pronouns, ovidius, metamorphoses, relative-pronouns

In this short passage by Ovid, the pronoun "quam" seems to be used as a third person pronoun.

> Inachus unus abest imoque reconditus antro
>   fletibus auget aquas natamque miserrimus Io
>   luget ut amissam. Nescit, vitane fruatur,
>   an sit apud manes; sed **quam** non invenit usquam,
>   esse putat nusquam atque animo peiora veretur.

Here's my translation:

> Inachus alone is absent, hidden deep within a cave, increasing the waters with his tears and, most miserable, mourning his daughter Io as lost. He does not know whether she enjoys life, or is among the shades; but [since] he has not found her anywhere, he thinks **her** to be nowhere, and dreads worse things in his mind. (Metamorphoses I.583-7)

You can see that I treated "quam" as a third person pronoun, translating it as "her". I have a few questions about this.

1. Am I correct in doing so? ("quam" = "her")
2. Is the relative pronoun commonly used as a third person pronoun, in classical Latin?
3. Do you think that Ovid may have preferred "quam" to "illam" because of its consonance with "usquam" and "nusquam"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Quam* here is being used as a normal relative, and could not be replaced with *illam*, since the relative clause *quam non invenit umquam* is the accusative subject of the verb *esse* in the accusative and infinitive construction introduced by *putat* in the main clause. A literal translation is: "[the one] whom (*quam*) he does not find anywhere, he believes to be nowhere".

Comment: Oh, you're right, I misread the passage.

Comment: Oh, I see. Would the relative clause introduced by quam be the accusative subject of esse? (As opposed to the object.) That would make more sense to me in an a.c.i. (Although perhaps with linking verbs, the distinction is not important.)

Comment: @ktm5124, you're right, sorry! It's the subject of the ACI construction -- corrected.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it is a normal relative use of *qui*, but with the antecedent (like *[eam] quam*) included in the relative pronoun. You could translate it literally as "but he thinks [her] *whom he does not find anywhere* to be nowhere", relative clause in italics.

---

Although it doesn't apply here, using *qui* as a demonstrative/personal pronoun is not uncommon. The Dutch term is *relatieve aansluiting* (I have forgotten the Latin term), when a relative pronoun is used where we would expect a demonstrative or personal pronoun. We were taught to translate such forms of *qui* as if it said *et/at ille/hic*, as it fits the sentence.

The distinction between relative, demonstrative/personal, possessive, and interrogative 3rd-person pronouns is relatively recent, such that e.g. Homer still often uses what is to us the article as a relative pronoun, and the relative as a possessive.

In Latin, too, the relative pronoun developed relatively recently (probably around late prehistory), out of a demonstrative or interrogative *qui*. At first this *qui* was always used interrogatively, or demonstratively with some subordinating or similar conjunction or particle, but then later it came be used alone as a subordinating pronoun (relative pronoun).

The construction used by Ovid is probably a remnant of that.

In German, the phaenomenon is called *relativ(isch)er Anschluß*. You may find more information in Kühner–Stegmann, *Ausführliche Grammanik der lateinischen Sprache* (1914), second volume, part 2, paragraph 197 (p. 319). (When the Germans call something ausführlich, you know it is twice that.)

The English term is *connective relative clause*.

Comment: I never knew that "qui" could be used demonstratively. When you say this, do you mean that "qui" is functioning as an adjective—either a relative adjective or a interrogative adjective? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: As you thinking of connective relatives? If so, this isn't an example of that, but a normal relative clause -- see my answer. (Unrelatedly, it's far from certain that the Latin use of *qui* as relative pronoun is a recent Latin-specific development -- it may already have been such in PIE; this is a long debated question.)

Comment: @ktm5124: TKR is right; I have updated the answer. But anyway, a connective relative functions like a coördinate conjunction + a form of *ille* or *hic*. It can be adjective or substantive, as all pronouns of the third person can.